# Bubble sort in double linked list

Tags: c++, visual-studio, c++11, bubble-sort

```
void sortTrain(TrainCar* head, bool ascending)
{
    TrainCar* current = head;
    int count = 1;
    int size = (getlength(head));
    if (ascending == 1)
    {
        for(int i = 0; i < size-1; i++)
        {
            while(current->next)
            {
                if((current->load) > ((current->next)->load))
                {
                    swapCar(head,count,count+1);
                }
                count++;
                current = current->next;
            }
        }
    }

    if (ascending == 0)
    {
        for(int i = 0; i < size-1; i++)
        {
            while(current->next)
            {
                if((current->load) < ((current->next)->load))
                {
                    swapCar(head,count,count+1);
                }
                count++;
                current = current->next;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Anyone helps me to fix the problem?
I don't know how to improve it.
Or any other code can do the same result?
Ascending when bool ascending is true,
otherwise, do descending.

Comment: ***Anyone helps me to fix the problem?*** You should tell us the problem instead of having us have to figure it out. Does it not sort correctly? does it crash? What happens?

Comment: I can tell you that at the end of each of your while loops, current will be null and no further sorting will happen so after the first iteration of your for loop the sorting is done even though you made only a single pass through your linked list.

Comment: *I don't know how to improve it.* -- If you took a look at the ascending and descending code, what is the difference?  It is one character, `<` and `>`.  Figure out how you can get rid of the code duplication (Hint:  Create a separate function that when given two items, returns `true` if the first item goes before the second item when sorted).

Comment: IMHO, you can improve the sorting of a doubling link list by turning it into a binary tree.

Comment: You might want to read [ask].

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The main error in the code you posted is that you are not resetting `current` and `count` after each iteration of the outer loop, i.e. try the following:

```
// ...

if (ascending == 1)
{
    for (int i = 0; i < size-1; i++)
    {
        TrainCar* current = head;
        int count = 0;
        while (current->next)
        {
            if ((current->load) > ((current->next)->load))
            {
                swapCar(head, count, count + 1);
            }
            count++;
            current = current->next;
        }
    }
}

// ...
```

The above should work if `swapCar` uses zero-based indices (I also changed it such that `count` is initialized to zero not one : don't ever use 1-based indices in C or C++; it is just confusing to do so).

However, it is a bad design to implement `swapCar` as taking indices. Each call to `swapCar` is going to execute in O(n) time, if you know what that means. You already have `current` and `current->next` sitting there: just swap their load values, then you don't even need to maintain a `count` variable at all.